# Gradle Plugin jar Dependencies

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle build that relies on a plugin (MyTools) which is compiled in the buildSrc directory. This part is working correctly. The issue I'm having is trying to import a class from an external jar to use in the myTools plugin's source.

My Directory Structure looks like this:
buildSrc
---build.gradle
---MyTools
-----build.gradle
-----settings.gradle
-----libs
-------yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar
-----src
-------main
---------groovy
-----------com
-------------my
---------------MyTools.groovy
---------------MyToolsPlugin.groovy
---------resources
-----------META-INF
-------------gradle-plugins
-------------gradle-plugins/MyTools.properties

The contents of MyTools/build.gradle are:
dependencies {
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

When I try to import com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.CssCompressor from MyTools.groovy, I 
get this message:

"unable to resolve class com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.CssCompressor"

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `compile` dependency, not a `runtime` dependency. Also, I don't see how the main build is going to pick up the plugin, given that it's located in a `MyTools` subdirectory (and `buildSrc` doesn't have a `settings.gradle`). Probably best to lift up `MyTools` into `buildSrc`.